# Sum of two columns in two different tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables -

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23 |
| B | 23 |
| C | 43 |
| D | 55 |
| E | 45 |
| F | 65 |
| G | 56 |
| H | 56 |

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| H | 34 |
| G | 45 |
| F | 67 |
| R | 78 |
| S | 78 |

I need to sum the values only if the cell exists in both the tables, if not I need the value against the respective cells

For example, since H is present in both tables, I need `H | (56+34) = 90`, and `E = 45` and `R = 78`, as these are present only in one of the tables

Answer (score 0):

One easy way using `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()`

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(TOCOL((A:A,D:D),1),TOCOL((B:B,E:E),1),SUM,,0)
```

---

One more way using `MMULT()`

```
=LET(
     φ, VSTACK(A1:B8,D1:E5),
     α, TAKE(φ,,1),
     δ, TAKE(φ,,-1),
     ε, UNIQUE(α),
     HSTACK(ε,MMULT(N(ε=TOROW(α)),δ)))
```

---

Using `Excel Formula` that should work with `Excel 2021`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _rngOne, Table1,
     _rngTwo, Table2,
     _r, SEQUENCE(ROWS(_rngOne)+ROWS(_rngTwo)),
     _c, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_rngOne)),
     _output, IFERROR(INDEX(_rngOne,_r,_c),INDEX(_rngTwo,_r-ROWS(_rngOne),_c)),
     _alpha, INDEX(_output,,1),
     _numeric, INDEX(_output,,2),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_alpha),
     CHOOSE({1,2},_uniq, MMULT(N(_uniq=TRANSPOSE(_alpha)),_numeric)))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1` & `Table2`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    DataTypeOne = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOne,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}}),
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    DataTypeTwo = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTwo,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}}),
    MergeTab = Table.Combine({DataTypeOne, DataTypeTwo}),
    GroupByCol = Table.Group(MergeTab, {"Col1"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Col2]), type nullable number}})
in
    GroupByCol
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

File For Download: **[Click Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckl6YxNhMMansDHJS?e=j7Q7C6)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't get groupby in my version of excel and the "let" formula throws an error as well. I am unable to attach screenshots in comments section

Comment: @GokulPradeepV so what is your excel version may I know that?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® 2021 MSO (Version 2312 Build 16.0.17126.20132) 64-bit

Comment: @GokulPradeepV I have added two approaches one using `Excel Formulas` another using `Power Query` also I have added the excel workbook, you can download from there. also note if that helps to resolve ensure to click on the tick mark beside the answer to accept it